# Xcode 6 beta 7: storyboard adds extra space on right and left sides

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, uistoryboard, xcode6

When I add subview to root ViewController's view, and with auto layout setup leadingSpace,trailingSpace,topSpace and bottomSpace to zero, there are appear some extra spaces on left and right sides (so if I print subview's frame its origin will be 16 and size less on 32 than should be).
So actually we get that leading and trailing spaces are not zeros...

[image]

As you can see on picture leading space - zero, but origin.x = 16

Earlier I wasn't working hard with auto layout, so my question is: 
Is it a bug of new Xcode or a feature?

P.S. All frames and constraints updated.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

iOS 8 adds the concept of [“content margins”](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW236) to `UIView`.  The [“What's New in Cocoa Touch” video from WWDC 2014](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=202) discusses content margins (under the title “Adaptive Margins”) starting at about 12m30s.

The default margins are 8 points on each side.  Each end of a layout constraint can be relative to a view's margin instead of to the view's true edge (use File > Open Quickly to go to the definition of `NSLayoutAttribute` to see the possibilities).

Your constraint is “relative to margin”.  When you create the constraint with the “Add New Constraints” popover, you can choose whether it's margin-relative or not:

[image: constraint-popover]

It always defaults to margin-relative; you have to turn the checkbox off every time you add constraints if you don't want them to be margin-relative.

You can't change whether a constraint is margin-relative in the quick-edit popover of your screen shot.  Instead, double-click the constraint to bring up its full Attributes inspector.  There, you can use the popup menus to select, for each end of the constraint, whether it's margin-relative or not:

[image: constraint-attributes]