# Why constraints is always Zero,is Storyboard preventing from edges?

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard

Let me trying to explain my question.I have noted from long time during app designing in `Storyboard/Xib`. In all cases for eg while dragging some controls into `storyboard` obviously it shows the blue lines helps to us place controls correctly.But it's seems prevent controls from `UIView`(main view) layout to place edges on controller.

When we trying to place controls the blue lines prevents us from edges.see below image

[image]

But why constraints always zero  even we are not placed at edges..it should be approximately 10,10,10..,

[image]

So my Qus is

1. Is `Storyboard/Autolayout` preventing to place controls at edges?
2. If yes.Then why all constraints is Zero ?
3. If No.Then what is the use of corner blue lines(eg:first image)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the **content margins** of each view which are 8 points away from its actual borders. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25702356/7456236) answer, which is explained it in details. Also you can place controls in the edges, just unchecking the `constrain to margins` will do that

Answer (score 2):

1. Storyboard/Autolayout is not preventing to place controls at edges, you can always place your objects there and apply auto layout by unchecking "Constrain to margin" option in auto layout menu.
2. It is zero because "Constrain to margin" option is checked. Placed object distance will be calculated from that bound margin line as long as "Constrain to margin" option is checked. Uncheck it and you will get exact values from edges.
3. The use of this blue line is... if you add any UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer, it will work outside those margin lines. placing an object between the edge and provided blue line may interfere with this kind of gesture recognizers.